# Подскажите метод шифрования

Tags: криптография

Есть некоторое сообщение S, которое нужно зашифровать/расшифровать **с помощью двух или более ключей** - по количеству владельцев этих ключей.

Важно чтобы процесс шифрования/расшифрования выполнялся всеми **по отдельности**, НО **в произвольном порядке**.

Пример.
Есть Вася и Миша, сначала Вася шифрует некоторую строку своим ключом, потом Миша своим. А чтобы расшифровать они также нужны оба, но порядок применения ключей не важен. Может Миша первым свой ключ использовать и отдать полурасшифрованное сообщение Васе, а может Вася.

Comment: RC4. При известном сообщении S пользователь может вычислить кусок битстрима другого пользователя не длиннее S, но не сам ключ.

Comment: Не подходит. На остальные сообщения можно будет наложить этот кусок битстрима и тем самым расшифровать. Ключ как таковой будет уже и не нужен. Если бы они последовательно шли, тогда да. А тут сообщения перемешаны случайным образом - сорри, это надо было сразу указать в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не припомню, чтобы существовала какая-то стандартизированная криптосистема с произвольным порядком двух и более ключей(поправьте, если ошибаюсь), но так или иначе реализовать произвольный порядок можно и самостоятельно одним из нижеприведенных способов:

```
1) M^(a*b*c*...)

Где M - открытое сообщение, преобразованное в число, а "a", "b" и "c" - множители(ключи) степени. Очевидно, что порядок ключей не играет роли при обратной
```

Или

```
2) M+a+b+c

Где "+" - операция сдвига по алфавиту(длины слагаемых ключей равны длине открытого сообщения). Очевидно, что вычитать суммы ключей можно также в обратном порядке
```

Comment: Мне еще исключающее или сразу в голову пришло, но все это слишком просто. Можно легко вычислить ключ второго пользователя

Comment: И каким вы образом будете расшифровывать `M^(a*b*c) mod m` не имея `M`? Искать корень степени `a` по модулю `m` не такая простая задача.

Comment: возьмем для простоты случай 2ух пользователей. Есть шифрованное сообщение M1^(a*b). Второй пользователь применяет свой ключ и передает M1^a первому. Тот применяет свой и получает M1. Теперь он применяет свой ключ к M1^(a*b) и вычисляет M1^b. M1 уже известно. Сложно ли вычислить b? Сообщение M2^(a*b) первый пользователь расшифрует уже без помощи второго

Answer (score 0):

Пусть каждый участник генерирует однократный ключ и шифрует тело сообщения им, а сам временный ключ шифрует своим личным ключом и добавляет в метаданные сообщения. Ну, или можно просто хранить этот однократный ключ у себя.

При расшифровке участник расшифровывает однократный ключ и записывает его в метаданных уже в открытом виде. Когда все ключи в метаданных оказываются открыты - последний участник может расшифровать ими сообщение по-очереди.

---

Если требуется именно что частичная расшифровка сообщения а не просто изменение метаданных - можно сделать так. Однократный ключ используется не для обычного шифрования сообщения - а для получения гаммы через криптостойкий *детерминированный* генератор случайных чисел.

Такой генератор можно сделать на основе любого блочного шифра (например, AES) - надо просто зашифровать однократным ключом последовательность натуральных чисел.

Полученная гамма просто побитово ксорится (XOR, "исключающее или") с телом сообщения. Кстати, такой алгоритм шифрования называется синхронным поточным шифром.

Достоинство этого метода - операции шифрования и дешифрования можно делать в любом порядке, нет необходимости накапливать список раскрытых временных ключей для расшифровки.

Недостаток этого метода - меньшая защищенность: если злоумышленник знает несколько бит исходного сообщения, он может незаметно заменить их на любые другие ничего не расшифровывая. Поэтому если вы решите так делать - обязательно добавьте к данным цифровую подпись.

---

PS обратите внимание на принципиальную несимметричность участников: Вася, который шифрует первым, видит нешифрованный текст, а потому он может его запомнить и в дальнейшем раскрыть даже без участия Миши какой бы алгоритм вы там не придумали.

Тем не менее, алгоритм имеет смысл если сообщение зашифровал кто-то третий, после чего раздал разные ключи Васе и Мише.